# Finger Print Scanner Driver Lenovo V570?

Tags: lenovo, scanner

Well since I recently chucked Windows7 from my laptop, I have been wanting to get my fingerprint scanner to work. I have had very little success in finding any good info on this issue. I am almost convinced that there are no drivers for the scanner. 
I like using this scanner for logins, yes I am lazy like that, I do enough typing as it is.

Has anyone had any success installing working drivers for finger print scanner?

This is a Lenovo Ideapad V570 - (do not know the other numbers) , i5 core Intel, 6 gigs, and in my opinion a wonderful Linux machine.

Here is the lsusb output:

```
 - rabbit@Lenovo-V570:~$ 
 - Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 - Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
 - Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
 - Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
 - Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07d7 Intel Corp.
 - Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58ea Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
 - Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d62:8001 Darfon Electronics Corp.

 - **Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc.**

 - Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

2nd from the bottom is the problem.

Edit:
Also it seems that there are no Linux drivers out for this scanner from what I gather, the model of scanner in the Thinkpads are different than those in the ideapads. I even checked on Ubuntu's catalog, they are all thinkpads, not ideapads, and the other thing the company lighTuning was bought out by Egistec, they seem to have put very little effort into making a Linux driver for this hardware.

Comment: Some info here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11046193

Comment: You can wrap your output of `lsub` use the '{}' symbol in editor

Comment: Yes I read that forum already, thank you though. @ coversnail

Comment: @ warl0ck, I just bulleted the damn thing, I am not that well versed in wrapping and it is late, so I just posted in bullets, so it is not a big mess.

Comment: Found someone working on a driver (recently): [EgisTec ES603 traces](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.fprint/1926) [edit] Found another: [Writing driver for Egistec reader (1c7a:0801)](http://www.mail-archive.com/fprint@reactivated.net/msg01634.html)

Comment: Whilst we appreciate the info - how does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Perhaps by mentioning that there is no driver, but one in development.

Comment: Well for now it is simply waiting for the driver, I think. I am not really up for trying to compile one, it has been suggested to me, but I will leave that to the experts. I will also reiterate this, the "IDEAPAD" does not seem to have the same support for the scanner. I have seen success only with Thinkpads, and if you look on Ubuntu's page they explicitly show ONLY "THINKPADS" as supported for hardware. Even though besides the stupid finger print scanner the Lenovo V570 Ideapad is well supported now with every other driver since 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but you might give this a try. https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fingerprint-gui  Seems to be the best bet I've seen around, though I'm no veteran myself.

Comment: I tried that, does not show device.

Answer (score 0):

I use ThinkFinger (an old project) and works fine on my W520

more information on ThinkWiki [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_enable_the_integrated_fingerprint_reader) and [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Integrated_Fingerprint_Reader)